# how to get javascript function paramater value in input field

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var tbl = document.getElementById("tblMain");
        if (tbl != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
                    tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () { getval(this); };
            }
        }
 
        function getval(cel) {
            alert(cel.innerHTML);
        }

$("#tblMain  tbody td").on('click', function() {
    $("#empname").val($(this).text());
    
 
$("#empname").on(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).next('#empname').focus();
    }
});
```

```html
<table align="center" id="tblMain" border="1" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                3
            </td>
            <td>
                4
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                5
            </td>
            <td>
                6
            </td>
            <td>
                7
            </td>
            <td>
               8
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                9
            </td>
            <td>
                0
            </td>
            <td>
                R3C3
            </td>
            <td>
                R3C4
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                R4C1
            </td>
            <td>
                R4C2
            </td>
            <td>
                R4C3
            </td>
            <td>
                R4C4
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<input type="text" id="empname" maxlength="1">
<input  id="empname2" type="text" maxlength="1" />
cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdzcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdzcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdzcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdzcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdzcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdzcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdzcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdzcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdzcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdzcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdzcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdzcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdzcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdzcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdzcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfhdfxdzdzdzdzdzdzfdzffzdfzdzdzdzdzdz
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What are we supposed to make out of the code, unless you explain what is the problem

Comment: i am trying to enter the value from number pad it is having four input field .for that i need a solution

Comment: var tbl = document.getElementById("tblMain");
        if (tbl != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
                    tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () { getval(this); };
            }
        }
 
        function getval(cel) {
            alert(cel.innerHTML); this alert messase is giving selected tr input vales as aletr but i wanted in the input field
        }
$("#tblMain  tbody td").on('click', function() {
    $("#empname").val($(this).text());
  });

Comment: alert messaging is giving the selected tr---1 etctill 9.but i dint want want alert message instead iwant to pass the valu in put field into four boesx as otp input

Comment: It is simply otp form is having table as key pad and input firld.for that i wanted solution

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a few end parenthesis and curly brackets. When you are debugging javascript, check the error console (by pressing F12 if in Chrome). Here is your javascript with the missing characters:

```
var tbl = document.getElementById("tblMain");
if (tbl != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
            tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () { getval(this); };
    }
}

function getval(cel) {
    alert(cel.innerHTML);
}

$("#tblMain  tbody td").on('click', function() {
    $("#empname").val($(this).text());
});

$("#empname").on(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).next('#empname').focus();
    }
});
```

You could honestly get rid of a lot of your Javascript code. Maybe you had all of the top stuff there just for testing? Or another form of assigning onclick handling? All you really need is the second half. The JQuery stuff. Although I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do with the second one.
 https://jsfiddle.net/c5n4h9zu/1/

Comment: ya thankyou but while i am copying to this forum i missed it but i want function getval(cel) {
    alert(cel.innerHTML);
}                                    alert message value needs to be pass into the input field?can you tell me how we can pass that>\?

Comment: I created a JSFiddle for you to check out. It works. You click a button and the number goes into the input field. I'm not sure what else you are hoping it will do. Go to the jsfiddle link I added and check it out.

Comment: this is what exactly i am tring to do this is sample link https://codepen.io/christiancoan/pen/PNyWWe.but i am dong throug table tr buttons

Comment: Why not just use the code shown on that page? You can just change the look of the buttons if you don't want circles. What you're asking is already done for you on that sample page.

Comment: i wanted in tables tr as a button..?

Comment: Ok, check this modification out: https://jsfiddle.net/c5n4h9zu/  I'm sure it could be done much more elegantly but I'll leave that for you to iron out.

Comment: actully it displays the clicked tr as alert and passing into one input field 2.but when i click the another tr it again pass the value into same input firld but it needs to be pass in other input field like otp form.it is not passing into other input field.four input filed need to pass when i m clicking thre tr by using auto focus –

Comment: Click the jsfiddle link again. Maybe I didn't hit update or save. It's working the way it shows up for me now

Comment: jsfiddle.net/c5n4h9zu this link ur telling?can yo uclarify pleae?it is still same issue?

Comment: Sorry. I forked it so it woldn't mess with what you were looking at before. Here is the correct link: https://jsfiddle.net/c5n4h9zu/1/

Comment: Great but it is accepting more than one number if type and also it accepting text as well

Comment: hi how can i  remove the typed numbers by pressing the [back]tr button

Comment: If you want only numbers change the input type to number. Add the maxlength back into the HTML and it will only be able to have one digit.

Comment: You did not have a back space button as an option / requirement in your original question. That changes a lot of things and honestly you should just take the code on that other website and change it if you want backspace. It isn't hard to do. But that is a separate question.

Comment: ok Thanks bro. i strgullling a lot thanks for the help.i will rasie saparely with i tried

Comment: i have mentioned like otp form otp form has the back button and l right?

Comment: hi it is enterting the value in the input field but  input field does not store the value after the entering ALSO

Comment: You keep adding on things you want this to do. Please mark an answer as accepted when it solves your original question / problem. If you want to add more functionality to your script, it is best to start with a new question using a properly functioning code base.

Comment: i am not able to rasie new question i have to wait two to 3 days but i want as soos as possible

Comment: question not answetrd properly

Comment: You didn't even ask a question in your original post. Your first comment when someone asked what you were trying to do was " 
i am trying to enter the value from number pad it is having four input field .for that i need a solution". That is what my solution does. It enters values from a number pad. This website is about solving problems you are having and helping you fix errors in your own code. Not about writing code for you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var toggle = "#empname";

$("#tblMain  tbody td").on('click', function() {
    switch (toggle) {
     case "#empname":
       $(toggle).val($(this).text());
       toggle = "#empname2";
       break;
      case "#empname2":
       $(toggle).val($(this).text());
       toggle = "#empname3";
       break;
      case "#empname3":
       $(toggle).val($(this).text());
       toggle = "#empname4";
       break;
      case "#empname4":
       $(toggle).val($(this).text());
       toggle = "#empname";
       break;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center" id="tblMain" border="1" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>R3C3</td>
    <td>R3C4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R4C1</td>
    <td>R4C2</td>
    <td>R4C3</td>
    <td>R4C4</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 
<input type="text" id="empname" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="empname2" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="empname3" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="empname4" value=""/>
```

What you could do (if I am understanding your question correctly), is add the onclick event handlers for each number. The code they would run would set the .value property of the inputs to the respective number pressed. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes Exactly your right.if possible give me solution for that thanks in advance

Comment: No problem. Give me a couple minutes and I will respond back. P.S. What is the problem with the JSfiddle made above by SactoJosh? Just so I can improve it. Thanks. It might take a bit longer actually. Will try to do it as fast as I can.

Comment: actully it displays the clicked  tr as alert and passing into one input field 2.but when i click the another tr it again pass the value into same input firld but  it needs to be pass in other input field like otp form.it is not passing into other input field.four input filed need to pass when i m clicking thre tr by using auto focus

Comment: OK. Instead of using autofocus, I will make it automatically know when to switch to the next input box. Would this be fine? P.S. I will edit my original response and add in the code for it.

Comment: Or do you still need my help?

Comment: i can type in that if possibe restricj all the special charaters and make it enter only number possible?

Comment: as well please add back button to delete number if possibe.could you give fina one having this changes like otp form

Comment: OK, I will work on it and see what I can do. And what are all the extra parts of the table for (the R#C#)?

Comment: I finished it. I edited my original post and added in the code for it. Instead of a back button, I had the program cycle through each input and change it depending on what input was last changed. Hope this works well for you!

Comment: ya Many thanks to you.but i want to back button needs to be delete from last input to first input.by using clicking the back button in the tr itsel so the tr will be like this <table align="center" id="tblMain" border="1" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>*</td>
    <td>back</td>
  </tr>

 </t

Comment: hi it is enterting the value in the input field but  input field does not store the value after the entering ALSO